# Cannot prepend element to a list

Tags: scala

I have this data structure:

```
var index : List[(Int, List[Int])] = Nil
```

Then, at some point I want to add some element to my index. I try to do:

```
index(position)._2 = new_elem :: index(position)._2
```

But the compiler complains that I am doing a `reassignment to val`.

If it could help, I create a new position into the index by the following line of code:

```
index = (p, Nil) :: index
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Use ListBuffer instead of List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem: the index is a variable (and can be changed), but the List is an immutable data structure, so only the whole list can be changed.

You can use [MutableList](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.MutableList) or [Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map).

Answer (score 2):

You can't reassign one part of a tuple, only the whole thing.  Try:

```
index(position) = (index(position)._1, new_elem :: index(position)._2)
```

[Scala API Tuple2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2)

See that `_1` and `_2` are `val`s

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which helped me undestand th problem. Howerever now I have got this new error: `value update is not a member of List[(Int, List[Int])`. Any idea?

Comment: As others have said, you can upgrade the outer list (as in, the one that holds the tuple, not the one within the tuple) to a `MutableList`.  This gives you access to this:  http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.MutableList
(Scroll down to "update").  I love the Scala API and it ought to give you enough information to get there.  Hope this helps!